# While fetching Coredata data, getting in non readable data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I am doing `Coredata` stuff in my app. I have not used much in my applications so far. Now, I just saved 3 strings for 3 keys for my entity.
It's saving okay. But, while fetching the records, i got it in non readable mode.

**My code**

```
//fetch data
-(NSMutableArray*)fetchUserInfo
{

NSPersistentContainer *container = kAppDelegateAccessor.persistentContainer;

managedObjectcontext = container.viewContext;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CollectionViewData" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectcontext];
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSError *error;
NSArray *dataArray=[managedObjectcontext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSMutableArray *fullDataArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (dataArray==nil) {

}
else
{
    for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
        Coredata *userData=(Coredata*)[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [fullDataArray addObject:userData];
    }
}
return fullDataArray;
}
```

And fetching data as

```
"<NSManagedObject: 0x6000002a0240> (entity: CollectionViewData; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://9BF8B113-771A-4611-8080-03C65A83A0F0/CollectionViewData/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
"<NSManagedObject: 0x6000002a02a0> (entity: CollectionViewData; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://9BF8B113-771A-4611-8080-03C65A83A0F0/CollectionViewData/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

Any help.

Comment: What's your question? Is it because you logged just `fullDataArray` and are surprised of `NSManagedObject` `description`? That's normal behavior. Did you try to check for its values and if they are correct?

Comment: What is the type `CoreData`. Why do you not use `dataArray`directly?

Comment: What is "non readable mode"? What problem are you trying to fix here?